# MailMessage - display only From and not Sender

Tags: c#, smtp, mailmessage

I am creating a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage and sending it using SmtpClient.

I send the email using SenderEmail@domain.com, i.e. that is the Sender and From is set to FromEmail@domain.com.

The receiver of the email will then see "SenderEmail on behalf of FromEmail". Ideally I simply want the from display to say "FromEmail" so receiver cannot see it is sent using SenderEmail@domain.com.

Is there any way to do that?

```
var sendOnBehalfOfEmail = "FromEmail@domain.com";

var mail2 = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
mail2.Sender = new MailAddress("SenderEmail@domain.com");
mail2.From = new MailAddress(sendOnBehalfOfEmail); 
mail2.ReplyToList.Add(sendOnBehalfOfEmail);
mail2.To.Add(new MailAddress("ReceiverEmail@domain.com"));
mail2.Subject = "Subject Test";
mail2.Body = "Body Test";

var credentials = new NetworkCredential("FromEmail", password);
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp...", 587))
{
    smtp.Credentials = credentials;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Send(mail2);
    smtp.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You can send from which name and email you want. `mail2.From = new MailAddress(sendOnBehalfOfEmail, sendOnBehalfOfName);`. But if your actual sender domain is not in `sendOnBehalfOfEmail's` spf records etc than it will always end up in the spam folder of the receiver (or deleted immediately).